# A single MAC Address on my network shows with 2 IPs

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, mac-address

I have a network monitoring app on my phone that shows each IP, MAC, and type of device on my network. While inspecting, I noticed that my laptop's MAC Address is repeated in **two IPs**. **I do not run any type of VMs and/or VPNs on my laptop.** Could this potentially be an intruder?

*My Wi-Fi Driver/Adapter: Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless N7260*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MAC address identifies the physical network interface adapter in a device, not the computer itself.  If your laptop has both wifi and ethernet support, it would have two MAC addresses, one for each network adapter.

So, what you're with the MAC address is completely expected. If you have multiple IPs assigned to your device, which is reasonable in a wide variety of situations, they would all be associated with the same MAC address.